the story of warming, which could grow

But the scope of the world’s transformation may just as quickly
eliminate the genre—indeed eliminate any effort to tell the story of
warming, which could grow too large and too obvious even for
Hollywood. You can tell stories “about” climate change while it still
seems a marginal feature of human life, or an overwhelming feature of
lives marginal to your own. But at three degrees of warming, or four,
hardly anyone will be able to feel insulated from its impacts—or want
to watch it on-screen as they watch it out their windows. And so as
climate change expands across the horizon—as it begins to seem
inescapable, total—it may cease to be a story and become, instead, an
all-encompassing setting. (from The Uninhabitable Earth (Adapted for
Young Adults) by David Wallace-Wells)


Which does the bold 'which' refer to?
a) warming
b) the whole preceding clause. '(the fact that) the scope of ~~ the story of warming'
c) the scope of the world's transformation
d) or else
The scope of the world's transformation may eliminate the genre just as quickly as what?
the scope of the world's transformation?? (the expanding speed of) the scope of the world's transformation?? or else?? I am not sure.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

(1) Which refers to [global] warming. (2) Presumably, just as quickly as something mentioned in a previous sentence. My guess is that it's the rapid growth of films about climate change.

Is the source of this paragraph online? If so, add a link so we can see the context.

@KateBunting Thank you for the answer to (1). The link for (2) is https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=Z7emEAAAQBAJ&newbks=0&lpg=PA90&dq="any effort to tell the story of warming%2C which could grow"&hl=ko&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q="any effort to tell the story of warming, which could grow"&f=false

@Barmar Thank you Barmar :) The link for (2) is https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=Z7emEAAAQBAJ&newbks=0&lpg=PA90&dq="any effort to tell the story of warming%2C which could grow"&hl=ko&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q="any effort to tell the story of warming, which could grow"&f=false

Unfortunately, that link leads to a passage in a script I can't read! Can you tell us what the previous sentence was?

Your quotation opens with the word "but". Everything in this quotation is a contrast to something that was said before it. You cannot understand the comparative "just as quickly" without the context.

@KateBunting What does it mean to be entertained by a fictional apocalypse as we stare down the possibility of a real one? One job of pop culture is always to serve stories that distract even as they appear to engage—to deliver sublimation and diversion. In a time of cascading climate change, Hollywood is also trying to make sense of our changing relationship to nature, which we have long regarded from at least an arm’s length—but which, amid this change, has returned as a chaotic force we nevertheless understand, on some level, as our fault.

@KateBunting The adjudication of that guilt is another thing entertainment can do, when law and public policy fail, though our culture, like our politics, specializes in assigning the blame to others—in projecting rather than accepting guilt. A form of emotional prophylaxis is also at work: in fictional stories of climate catastrophe, we may also be looking for catharsis and collectively trying to persuade ourselves we might survive it.

@Astralbee My two comments above are the preceding paragraph.

My two comments above are the second paragraph, and my original question paragraph is the third paragraph. If you need the first paragraph, I will show you below.

It seems that Barmar has managed to read several earlier paragraphs, and I agree with his answer.

On-screen, climate devastation is everywhere you look, and yet nowhere in focus, as though we are displacing our anxieties about global warming by restaging them in theaters of our own design and control—perhaps out of hope that the end of days remains “fantasy.” Game of Thrones opens with an unmistakable climate prophecy, but warns “winter is coming”; the premise of Interstellar is an environmental scourge, but the scourge is a crop blight. Children of Men depicts civilization in semi-collapse, but collapsed by a fertility menace.

Mad Max: Fury Road unfurls like a global-warming panorama, a scrolling saga of a world made desert, but its political crisis comes, in fact, from an oil shortage. . The protagonist of The Last Man on Earth is made that way by a sweeping virus, the family of A Quiet Place is hushed by giant insect predators lurking in the wilderness, and the central cataclysm of the “Apocalypse” season of American Horror Story is a throwback—a nuclear winter. In the many zombie apocalypses of this era of ecological anxiety, the zombies are invariably rendered as an alien force, not an endemic one.

That is, not as us.


"which" refers to global warming. In general, when a pronoun is used this way, its antecedent is the closest preceding noun phrase for which it makes sense. Since there's no reason why "which" couldn't refer to warming, that's how it's understood.

If you read the earlier paragraphs in the chapter, it lists a number of TV shows and movies that have come out in the past few years that depict climate-change disasters. So "just as  quickly" refers to how quickly these productions have come out, trying to warn us about the dangers that are looming. If we don't solve the problem soon, warnings like this will become moot -- you can't warn against something that has already happened. So once it becomes the "new normal", they believe that this genre of entertainment fiction may disappear.



Thank you for your kind answer! I think 'warming' seems to be appropriate, too, but some say to me that 'the story of warming' is the antecedent. What do you think of this?

It's possible, although "large" is not usually a way to describe a story.
